# Confidence interval for the slope of a regression line

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I have the following problem.

**Problem**

A company has a revenue x and a surplus y. $\Sigma x=1109$,  $\Sigma y=151$, $\Sigma x^2=186689$, $\Sigma y^2=4017$  and $\Sigma xy=26775$. It is said to be a linear dependence between x and y.

Find a 95 % confidence interval for $\beta$ , the slope.

**Attempt to solution**
I have used these formulas 
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I use the information to find se?

Thank you.

Comment: In other words, you want to compute $\alpha$ from $t_{\alpha/2,\,n-2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{S_{xx}}}$. You'll need either a table or software.

Comment: Yes, $\hat{\sigma}$ is the only thing I can't calculate.

Comment: Why not type out the equations instead of posting images?

Comment: The source you use for the formulae here ought to define $\hat\sigma^2$.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve the linear regression in matrix formulation you will obtain

$$\hat{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}X^TX \end{bmatrix}^{-1}X^Ty.$$

The inverted matrix is often referred to as $C$ matrix (note the inversion!).

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}X^TX \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}N & \sum_{n=1}^Nx_n\\\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n & \sum_{n=1}^Nx^2_n \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

The diagonal values of this matrix (after inverting!) are $c_{00}$ and $c_{11}$. The confidence interval for the parameter $\beta_j$ is given by

$$\hat{\beta}_j \pm t_{df=N-p-1}\left(1-\dfrac{\alpha}{2(p+1)}\right)s_\text{e}\sqrt{c_{jj}},$$

in which $p$ is the number of independent variables and 
$$s_\text{e}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^N(y_n-\hat{y}_n)^2}{N-p-1}}.$$

You will need the sample size $N$ for that, but it could happen that it gets canceled out. Can you solve it from here?